# How to have EditText with border in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an Android app. I need to know how we can have a EditText with border. In Lolipop they have completely changed the EditText style. Can we do it without using drawables?

Comment: My ask should answer yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61398289/android-how-can-i-add-a-border-around-textview-responsive-with-last-item-inside

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Write editTextBackground.xml in drawable folder in resources

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/borderColor" />
</shape>
```

don't forget to declare color in resources named `borderColor`.

and assign this background to the `EditText` in xml background attribute

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:background="@drawable/editTextBackground"
    />
```

and it'll set border to `EditText`.

### **UPDATE**

You can change border of edit text without drawable by using `style` attribute

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
```

for more details visit [customize edit text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081900/how-to-customize-edittext-field-in-android-using-appcompat-v721)

Comment: >Without using drawables

Comment: `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"` doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 28):

You can use a drawable. Create a drawable layout file in your drawable folder. Paste this code. You can as well modify it - border.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/divider" />
<solid
    android:color="#00FFFFFF"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"/>
<padding
    android:left="10dp"
    android:top="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

in your EditText view, add

```
android:background="@drawable/border"
```

Comment: >Without using drawables

Answer (score 14):

You can do it using xml.

Create an xml layout and name it like **my_edit_text_border.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#949494"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Add background to your `Edittext`

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/editText1"
 ..
 android:background="@layout/my_edit_text_border">
```

Answer (score 3):

For correct work your shape should be with selector and item tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="@color/shape_border_active"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty solution I have used is to place the EditText inside of a FrameLayout. The margins of the EditText control the thickness of the border and the border color is determined by the background color of the FrameLayout.

Example:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

But I would recommend, and the vast majority of the time I do, drawables for borders. [Elite's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1911941/elite) answer is what I would go for in that case.

Answer (score 0):

To the option border in **TextView** doesn't exist, so the create border for your **TextView** you should do these steps:

1. Steps
   1.1 create **xml** file in **drawable** folder and use this code:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <stroke
>         android:width="3dp"
>         android:color="@color/black" />
>     <solid
>         android:color="#00FFFFFF"
>         android:paddingLeft="10dp"
>         android:paddingTop="10dp"/>
>     <padding
>         android:left="10dp"
>         android:top="10dp"
>         android:right="10dp"
>         android:bottom="10dp" />
> </shape>
> ```
>
> ⚠️ warning: do not create xml file in the layout because

2.1 call the drawable in your TextView as background

2. Overview ️
   [image]