# Outlined TextField with AndroidX

Tags: android, android-edittext, textfield, androidx

I updated my project to androidx:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

Now the OutlinedBox from [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52401242/outlined-edit-text-from-material-design) with MaterialComponents is causing my app to crash.

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

I could create the outline as a background with an editText background ([this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762006/how-to-have-edittext-with-border-in-android-lollipop)), but is there a way to do it with androidx and material components?  Or perhaps I'm missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"` is belonging to Material Components, you need to implement it by add this dependency:  `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'`. And remember to inherit your app theme from Material Components too:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

For more detail, you can read [this guide](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)